# How is SO(2) compact according to this definition?

Tags: mathematical-physics, group-theory

According to [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CompactLieGroup.html), a compact Lie group is a group whose parameters vary over a closed interval. I'm not sure if this definition [is rigorous enough](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1143829/).

I've also seen a similar definition [here](http://www2.ph.ed.ac.uk/~ldeldebb/docs/QM2/chap4.pdf):

> Note that the parameter labelling the rotations varies in a compact interval
>   (the interval $[0, 2π)$ in this case). Groups with parameters varying over compact intervals are called compact groups.

Anyway, wouldn't this definition imply that **rotations do not form a compact group**, since $[0,2\pi)$ is not closed, so it's not compact? Am I missing something?

Comment: MathWorld's definition doesn't make a lot of sense, because usually you can't cover the whole group (or manifold in general) with a single coordinate chart.

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: Following the definition of compact group, you should prove that there is a topology on $SO(2)$ such that it becomes compact. What I always thought to be the working trick is that if the Lie parameter of the group is in a (locally) compact space then the group is (locally) compact. In this context, I would interpret the parameter of $SO(2)$ to belong to the one-dimensional circle $\mathbb{S}^1$ (since it is an angle) more than in a subset of reals; i.e. it may be parametrized by $[0,2\pi)$ but thought as the set of points in a circle with the suitable compact topology.

Comment: @Qmechanic I asked a similar question there, but I've encountered this definition in a physics context so it might mean something different than what is would mathematically imply.

Comment: Physicists are not good at giving rigorous definitions. Use the usual topological compactness property as yuggib indicates.

Comment: Really, we want to think of the interval as $[0,2\pi]/\sim$ where $0 \sim 2\pi$ is the only equivalence (and given the quotient topology). In this sense the interval is compact (as a quotient of a compact space).

Answer (score 2):

This is a bad definition. There is indeed a map, even a continuous bijection, from $[0, 2\pi)$ to $SO(2)$. However, this map is not a [homeomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeomorphism), so its existence does not imply that $[0, 2\pi)$ and $SO(2)$ have the same topological properties, such as [compactness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_space).

In more detail, there is a sequence $x_n = 2 \pi - \frac{1}{n}$ in $[0, 2\pi)$ that does not have a limit, so $[0, 2\pi)$ is not sequentially compact. However, the image of this sequence in $SO(2)$ just converges to the identity, so this doesn't prevent $SO(2)$ itself from being sequentially compact.